# Bootstrap 5 carousel slide animation not proper in production

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

[image]

I used bootstrap 5 carousel it works well in my local. But it breaks after build and published to production. I don't know why.

I have attached my code here for your reference. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" *ngIf="banners.length">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button *ngFor="let item of banners; let i = index"
            type="button"
            [attr.data-bs-target]="'#carouselExampleIndicators'"
            [attr.data-bs-slide-to]="i"
            [class.active]="i === 0"
            [attr.aria-current]="i === 0 ? 'false' : null">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active " *ngFor="let item of banners">
      <img loading="eager" [ngSrc]="item?.image" class="d-block" width="1480" height="405" style="height: fit-content; width: 100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Pease make a repro case for your issue. Use Stackblitz for instance and load boostrap into it. Then we can experiment with it or even better: your repro case will start working and you will be able to find an anwser